# How to print a HTML content without showing the print dialog with specific printer on tablet(chrome) by C# or JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How do I print HTML content without showing the print dialog with a specific printer on a tablet(chrome) by C# or JS when I click a button?

I have checked several libraries but it seems unable to show the dialog on the Chrome app. Is there any way to do it? I have also tried to see if it is possible to use 'StaTaskScheduler' but it seems it is not a Nugget and I have no idea how to download and use it.

Thank you guys. I think I have solved the problem. Would you mind re-opening the question so that others can reference to here?

what you need to do is add these 2 namespace on top

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;
```

Here is the c# code and We can call this function anywhere and pass the variables to it.

```
public static void PrintD(string text)
    {
        
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) => {
            args.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10));
        };
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "HK_Canon uniFlow SecurePrint";
        if (pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible with JS. No idea with C#. Either way it sounds like a breach of security and use trust.

Comment: Not possible. And what if you have multiple printers. How would the code know which one to use? You can send something to a printer directly, but it has to be done in the backend.

Comment: @VDWWD I will only connect to one printer. How can I do it through c#?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have solved the question on my own, would you mind re-opening the question so that others can reference it here?

Comment: @VDWWD I have solved the question on my own, would you mind re-opening the question so that others can reference it here?

Comment: Done. Voted to re-open.

Comment: If the question gets reopened, please may you remove the solution from the question and move it to an answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just let me know when the question is reopened thx

Comment: The question is not closed.

Comment: I was the last (?) to vote for reopen in the past few minutes.. so the question is open again @pluto_99

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I think I have solved the problem. Would you mind re-opening the question so that others can reference to here?

what you need to do is add these 2 namespace on top

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;
```

Here is the c# code and We can call this function anywhere and pass the variables to it.

```
public static void PrintD(string text)
    {
        
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) => {
            args.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10));
        };
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "HK_Canon uniFlow SecurePrint";
        if (pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
    }
```